# Firestore read/write pricing; does .limit(25) counts as 25 reads or one?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a bit confused as to whether a query like the one below counts as one read or 25 reads for Firestore pricing ?

```
queryRef.limit(25).get().then(()=>{

...

});
```

I understand that in the [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) chart a "document read" has been defined as the unit but I am a bit confused about a query like above and need a confirmation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your query returns 1 document, you will be charged 1 read.  If your query returns 25 documents, you will be charged 25 reads.  A document does not have the be "read" to be omitted in a query, **except** in the case of using an offset to skip documents.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> **There are no additional costs for using cursors, page tokens, and
>   limits. In fact, these features can help you save money by reading
>   only the documents that you actually need.**
>
> However, when you send a query that includes an offset, you are
>   charged a read for each skipped document. For example, if your query
>   uses an offset of 10, and the query returns 1 document, you are
>   charged for 11 reads. Because of this additional cost, you should use
>   cursors instead of offsets whenever possible.

Comment: As you said @Doug Stevenson firestore charges on the basis of document reads let say i create a single document and then nest inside or pupulate it with heavy data will that be counted as a single read .As we can do multiple maps and list inside a single document so will it help to reduce writes.

Comment: On this answer, the opposite is told, meanly charging only once for one query. Is it wrong? --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65729373/20742532

Comment: @JeremyFc That answer has been commented on, and is not the most upvoted answer on that question.